# Using git-annex with GitLab and best place to host

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using gitlab to remotely host my project. It will contain big binary files so I want to use git-annex to keep the repo size low. I believe using GitLab remotely does support git-annex. I understand the theory of git-annex of effectively using symlinks to the big files. However what I don't understand is the best place to store these big files for them to be symlinked. The documentation gives examples of using a USB drive but that is not really acceptable for me. Ideally I want something hosted in the cloud that I can access anywhere. It should really also track changes to the big files so I can revert. Maybe even inside another gitlab repo. I haven't used it before so I may have slightly misunderstood its usage.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? Could you post it as an answer if you did?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [gitlab.com](https://about.gitlab.com/) (a cloud service) to host your projects, then read the *git-annex* tip [Centralized git repository on GitLab](https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/centralized_git_repository_tutorial/on_GitLab/). You can test it even with a free account.

Additionally, the article [Storing large binary files in git repositories](http://blog.deveo.com/storing-large-binary-files-in-git-repositories/) compares other tools that may be used to solve this problem.